# Laravel Authentication using Ajax

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I had a problem with authentication using ajax calls in Laravel 5.1.
It is related to csrf token.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours and hours of research, I've found a solution.
Here are the steps and hope this helps.

We need to add this meta tag to use csrf token in javascript.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And then, ajax call for authentication.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

$.post('/auth/login', {name : username, password : pswd}, 
        function(result){
            if (result == 'success'){
                closeDefineUserLocation();
            } else {
                $('.loginErrorText').val('Username or Password was incorrect!');
            }
        });
```

In the Controller routed by 'auth', create a function called login.

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $email = $request->input('name');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))){
            return 'success';
        }
        return 'failed';
    }
```

That's it.
Hope this helps.